# How to batch remove local branches in SourceTree, which remote equivalents have been already removed in the origin?

Tags: git, macos, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Sometimes it's desirable to have local branches in SourceTree even when remote equivalents on the origin don't exist but in my case I want to remove all (or specific) local branches in batch.

Right now my **SourceTree** keeps a lot of local *"feature"* and *"bugfix"* branches, that were made from remotes ages ago (one branch - one ticket).

I did some work, I pushed and finished working on them. Pull request was merged, branch was closed but I didn't delete my local branch straight away. Local copies exist on my machine and after some time the list grows and grows.

Is there a "one-click / command" solution to get rid of all local branches that don't have equivalents in a remote repo.

Blurred area contains local branches. Let's say I would like to remove all except develop or be able to specify in a batch and then press magic "clean" button. Does SourceTree offer such feature?

[image]

Comment: Is it ok for you to use command line ? If true, you can do something like that `git branch | grep -v develop | xargs git branch -d`. It will remove all branch listed by the git branch command, except `develop` you filter with grep.

Comment: @Flows, CLI is fine of course. Once I will execute this command, the changes will be reflected in SourceTree automatically?

Comment: Yes it should (I didn't tested). At least re-launch SourceTree

Comment: Does the answer I wrote below is working for you ? Please comment the answer if you still have issues

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using command line

```
git branch | grep -v develop | xargs git branch -d
```

It will remove all branch listed by the `git branch` command, except `develop` you filter with grep.